# How to make CLion use "#pragma once" instead of "ifndef ... def ..." by default for new header files?

Tags: include, header-files, clion, pragma, include-guards

By default, CLion will add the following lines to a newly created header file:

```
#ifndef SOME_NAME_H
#define SOME_NAME_H
.... your code here
#endif //SOME_NAME_H
```

But I like `#pragma once` more. How can I configure CLion so that it uses `#pragma once` by default for new header files?

Comment: This question can be tagged with [tag:include-guard].

Comment: [I found instructions for this on their site.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/header-guards.html#edit-hg)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to `File-> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates`. You will find there 3 tabs, namely, `Templates`, `Includes`, and `Code`. Now under `Templates` choose for example *C Header File*. Insert `#pragma once` to replace its content. Now every time you add a new Header from project menu you will have your template.

Comment: How should I modify this so that it uses `#pragma once`?

Comment: Note: `#pragma` is invalid [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) template because `#foo` will be parsed as a directive named `foo`. It's safer to use [literal syntax](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#literals) here, like `#[[#pragma]]# once`.

Comment: Or [escape the directive](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#escaping-vtl-directives) like `\#pragma once`.

Comment: For `CLion 2021, use CLion > Preferences... > Editor > File and Code Templates > C++ Class Header`.

Comment: @FranklinYu It's impressive how something so convenient as `#pragma once` finds so much opposition. Named include guards are incredibly error prone, I wouldn't put it in any proximity of the term "safer".